# Different behaviour with echo vs printf command line arguments in zsh

Tags: shell, zsh, command-line-arguments, parameter-expansion

I have a simple program to print the command line arguments in zsh. However, I see different behaviour with printf vs echo. Can anyone explain?

```sh
#!/bin/zsh
echo "$# @ : "$@"   "
printf "\n"
printf "$# *  $*   "
printf "\n"
printf "$# @ : "$@" \n"
```

Output:

```
batman$ ./args  a b c d
4 @ : a b c d   

4 *  a b c d   
4 @ : abatman$ //also gobbles up the newline!!
batman$
```

Comment: Many differences. For instance, `printf` interprets the first parameter as a format specifier. You can see the effect when you do a `./args '%s %s` x y` with your example script.

Answer (score 1):

`echo` and `printf` (and `print`) are different commands with different syntaxes and behaviors. Read the documentation for more info:

- [`echo`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-echo)
- [`print`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-print)
- [`printf`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-printf)

In Zsh, you should always prefer `print` or `printf` over `echo`. `echo` is mostly just there for compatibility with other shells.